# http://seller.samsungapps.com/ - Choosing a Category?

Tags: samsung-mobile

How can I choose a category when submitting a new app in http://seller.samsungapps.com/

Under the Category menu all I see is "Main Category" or "Galaxy Specials"

When I choose Main Category, then I get no submenu, and it won't let me submit the game

If I choose Galaxy Specials \ Other, it tells me:

```
The registered binaries do not meet the category conditions for GALAXY Specials. The GALAXY Specials category can be selected only if at least one binary supports GALAXY Specials. You can go to ‘Binary>Advanced Mode>Binary Details’ to check the supported GALAXY Specials options.
```

So, how can I submit the game?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Samsung's acceptance process.

Comment: Have the same problem. Anyone got it to work?

Comment: No, I still don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 13):

If you have implemented one of the Samsung SDK, this line is missing in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just put this line in your manifest.xml and everything will be OK. I just published this way.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

100% works to me. 
i had the same problem to upload my app on Samsung apps sellers, but after adding the following permission now it worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
```