# Cordova: How is it possible to edit <uses-permission> of android manifest?

Tags: cordova

I'm using a cordova cloud compiler, and I'm required to add a `<uses-permission>` configuration targetting android manifest xml file. So, is there any way to edit `<uses-permission>` of android manifest directly from cordova config files?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a readymade plugin available in cordova that suits your requirement. This custom config plugin lets you update platform configuration files based on custom preferences and config-file data defined in config.xml that are not supported out-of-the-box by Cordova/Phonegap.

Request you to check out this [custom-config-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) which lets you update the uses-permission too in AndroidManifest.xml using config.xml file changes. Do check out the example config.xml file in the link which should help. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is still not solved. I tried installing the plugin, and then adding `<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application">
      <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
    </config-file>` under `<platform name="android">`, but after compiling, I found that the setting failed to solve the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068907/http-seller-samsungapps-com-choosing-a-category, that I was having.

Comment: I don't know, I'm using a Cordova Cloud Compiler (Cocoon.io).

Comment: @user6039980 so you will not be able to get the apk as well?

Comment: No, the compilation completed successfully, but after sending the app to samsungapps I have been still facing the same problem as in the link above.

Comment: @user6039980 But without validating manifest XML we can't segregate whether it is the problem with XML setting or setting not impacting in the device.

Comment: Is it possible to generate the manifest xml file using only cordova cli, and without installing android ide?

Comment: @user6039980 very much possible. Just execute Cordova platform add android command and then execute Cordova build android command.It will create manifest XML file in platforms/android folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113449/discussion-between-user6039980-and-gandhi).

Comment: I solved my problem via switching to Monaca.io: it has good IDE integration for Android: so that I found there the Androidmanifest.xml and edited it. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user6039980 Glad you cracked it. Cheers