# Can a Codenameone Android build be published on the Galaxy Store?

Tags: codenameone

I am getting frustrated with Google's Play store. My app won't appear in searches (at all). There isn't a "new this week" section where users can find new stuff from indie devs such as myself. Top results usually include hillarious reviews that smell fishy

I contacted Google and they said that I can pay them money to appear in top searches (via ads) and this way improve my "market strategy". I am just trying to share my free app so that others can use it, I have no market strategy

As a result, I am going to focus on my Apple Store version (which is performing much better). I am also exploring the option of publishing on Galaxy Store, Huawei Store, etc

I tried uploading to Galaxy Store but upon submitting the app I get the following error:
`The registered binaries do not meet the category conditions for Galaxy Specials`

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068907/http-seller-samsungapps-com-choosing-a-category) I can see that something needs to be added in the manifest file. Is there a way to do this via build hints in CodenameOne? I also read that a "Galaxy SDK" needs to be added somewhere. Is this a prerquisite and if so, how would one add it in CodenameOne?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but this might work, add the build hint:

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name=”com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY”/>
```

If the build hint already exists then just tack this string to its ending.

Comment: Thx Shai. I will try it next month and let you know